# ionic 3 from tabbed page to normal page

Tags: ionic-framework

Pages structure is: `Tabs(page1,page2,page3)`.

When I click a button within in page1, I want to go to page4, 
but now we still can see tab, how to make page4 displays as a normal page and can back to tabbed page.

In page1, I use below line to go to page4

```
this.navCtrl.push(page4);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could first try the following, which is **for test only** to understand
that this is achievable:

pass params to the ion-tabs like this:

```
<ion-tabs>
 <ion-tab [root]="tabMap" [rootParams]="tabParams" tabIcon="map"></ion-tab>
 <ion-tab [root]="tabList" [rootParams]="tabParams" tabIcon="list"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Prepare the params in the tabs.ts like this:

```
  ionViewWillEnter() {
   this.tabParams.parentNav = this.navCtrl;
  }
```

So in the inner page (page1, 2, 3) you can retrieve it, place it in a variable e.g. parentNav, and when you want to navigate out of the tabs page to do a this.parentNav.push(page4).

**The proper way** I think is to use events [events: ionic forum](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/)

So in the tabs.ts page you could have this piece of code:

```
  events.subscribe('tabs:newPage', (page) => {
  this.navCtrl.push(page);
 });
```

And in each page, or in a service you could have:

```
newPage(page) {
 console.log('navigate to a new page, not a tab')
 this.events.publish('tabs:newPage', page);
}
```

Comment: even I already solve the problem,your answer is still very useful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What ionic is ?

If lazy loading,maybe ionic 3 , hod did you declare page4?

You have to push it like this : `this.navCtr.push('page4');`

If is all ok try this (it 's extracted form an app example) :

```
static get parameters() {
  return [[IonicApp], [NavController], [ConferenceData], [UserData]];
}

constructor(app, nav, ...) {
  // all of the constructor code
}

tourFunction() {
  let nav = this.app.getComponent('nav');

  nav.push('page4');
}
```

[Ref](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-nav-push-outside-an-ion-tabs/40860/9)